# Set a div expandable on small device

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I try to expand a div while hovering it but only when the website is displayed on a small or x-small device. Is that possible ? See a picture below of what I try to achieve :

[image]

So far I have been able to only hide the yellow div when displaying the page on small device, but I have no idea about how to only reduce it and make it expandable.

Should I create a new div with those specifications and display it only on small device instead of the yellow div ? Any help and advices welcome !

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-0 d-none d-lg-block no-float" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-10 no-float" style="background-color:pink;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
    </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2 no-float" style="background-color:blue;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 800) 
 $('.testblock').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {
   $(".testblock").addClass("col-sm-2");
   $(".testblock").removeClass("col-sm-1");
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
  $(".testblock").removeClass("col-sm-2");
   $(".testblock").addClass("col-sm-1");
  }
 });
});
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wL7snqxe/